# How to copy and rename file listed in TXT file?

Tags: command-line, rename, cp

I need to copy all files listed in TXT file from one location to another location.

```
/1132526906_tt_nad87_1.jpg  /thumb/t1132526906_tt_nad87_1.jpg
/1132526906_tt_nad87_10.jpg /thumb/t1132526906_tt_nad87_10.jpg
/1132526906_tt_nad87_11.jpg /thumb/t1132526906_tt_nad87_11.jpg
/1132526907_tt_nad87_12.jpg /thumb/t1132526907_tt_nad87_12.jpg
/1132526907_tt_nad87_13.jpg /thumb/t1132526907_tt_nad87_13.jpg
/1132526908_tt_nad87_14.jpg /thumb/t1132526908_tt_nad87_14.jpg
```

I can create a CSV file and divide `source` and `target` with some usable character.

**Example**

I would like to **copy** file `1132526906_tt_nad87_1.jpg` from `./` to `/thumb/t1132526906_tt_nad87_1.jpg` - rename and move.

**Question**

Is there some command line command to do it? I found examples but these examples do only copying (without rename).

**UPDATE**

I created this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="/data/web/web/gallery/data.csv"

while IFS=',' read from to
do
    echo "from: $from, to: $to"
done < "$input"
```

but no line is "echoed", it seems that `data.csv` file is not read. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Use `#!/bin/sh` no bash required so far.

Comment: What application and operating system was used to create the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's example, the rename and change seems fairly consistent, eg `filename.jpg` seems always prefixed with same path plus a "t" becoming `thumb/tfilename.jpg` . If this is the case then its possible to do something simpler.

If all are destined for "thumb/" directory.

Have test files abc.jpg, xyz.jpg in current directory.

Here is sample file list

```
$ cat testfile
abc.jpg
xyz.jpg
```

### Test

It is helpful to do test version of the command with an echo to see what the code will do:

```
$ while read my_file; do
   echo cp -a "$my_file" "thumb/t$my_file"
done < testfile
```

Test result:

```
cp -a abc.jpg thumb/tabc.jpg
cp -a xyz.jpg thumb/txyz.jpg
```

- `while read my_file; do ... done` syntax will process stdin , line by line
- `< testfile` uses `<` to redirect `testfile` to stdin, so the while statement reads it
- `my_file` is a variable we made up to hold the input, which as we see in the body of the code can be referenced with `$my_file`
- use quotes to avoid potential problems if file names have spaces or other wierd characters that may break the spaces that `cp` command uses to recognize arguments

### Final

If satisifed with the test echo results we can remove the echo to actually carry out the command:

```
$ while read my_file; do
  cp -a "$my_file" "thumb/t$my_file"
done < testfile
```

When you check the `thumb/` directory you will see the two test files copied there.

### Final, with Feedback

By default `cp` gives no feedback unless there are errors. So if you are copying hundreds or thousands of files, it can potentially seem as if nothing is happening at all. To see feedback use the verbose option `-v`:

```
$ while read my_file; do
  cp -av "$my_file" "thumb/t$my_file"
done < testfile
```

Result:

```
`abc.jpg' -> `thumb/tabc.jpg'
`xyz.jpg' -> `thumb/txyz.jpg'
```

Comment: No. I need to copy two files with different names. This is only coincidence what you noticed about file names, so your solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

That's simplest with `xargs`:

```
< file-list.txt  xargs -n2 cp -v
```